# how to add end of line of each line

Tags: string, bash, shell, git-bash

```
cat file | jq -r '.item[].hostname'
server1
server2
server3
```

I store the output on file

```
cat file | jq -r '.item[].hostname' > server
```

and I store into array

```
IFS=$'\n' arr_server=($(cat server))
```

I print the array, but is not that I want

```
for ((i=0; i<${#arr_server[@]}; i++)); do echo "Host: [${arr_server[i]}]"; done
]OST: [server1
]OST: [server2
HOST: [server3]
```

why is change the string value. I use windows git bash

vim server, I use set list

```
server1$
server2$
server3$
```

Comment: Your input file or the json contains has dos lines endings. Do not use `$(cat`. Use `@csv` or `@sh` and use `readarray`.

Comment: do you have an instance please

Comment: Example? I think something along `tmp=$(jq -r '.item[].hostname | @sh' file); eval "arr_server=($tmp)"`, but I would feel safer with `IFS=$'\t' read -r arr_server < <(jq -r '.item[].hostname | @tsv')`

Comment: @KamilCuk what's `@csv` and `@sh`? I don't recognise this as a bash thing. Is it a windows / gitbash thing?

Comment: hi @TasosPapastylianou it's a jq builtin operator https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#format-strings-and-escaping . for example `jq '.[] | @tsv`

Comment: @KamilCuk ah ... I completely missed the fact that it was appearing inside the quotes ... I thought it was a command that was being piped to. Thanks!